# Tumblr: How do I make the "Previous Page" Button visible on the first site?

Tags: css, tumblr

So instead of having a usual previous and next page link on my Tumblr, I'd like to have some sort of directional pad as my navigation.

And yes, I managed to display all the arrows with the links to the Index Page, the Archive and the next page. However, you probably all know that Tumblr has that code that disables the "Previous Page" Button when on the first page and the "Next Page Button" when on the last page. I want them to be visible, however.

The code is what you might see everywhere. I just don't know what to adjust.

```
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}" class="jump_page">◄</a>
{/block:PreviousPage}

{block:NextPage}
<a href="{NextPage}" class="jump_page">►</a>
{/block:NextPage}
```

I'm pretty much a newcommer when it comes to css, so I am sorry, and I am sorry if the answer to this topic already exists somwhere; but really, I couldn't find it and maybe I don't even know how to search properly, but I tried, and now I need help.

Alright, thanks for reading and I hope someone has the answer here.

Comment: Haven't tested this but just try removing {block:PreviousPage} {/block:PreviousPage} and the same for the NextPage wrapper.

Comment: What @lharby said. The two blocks check to see if prev / next navigation is available, and then renders the HTML. Remove the blocks, removes the checks and will render the HTML regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Either hide the current page, when the previous page is available like this:

```
  <!-- some styling -->
  <style>
    #PageNavi{
      position:relative;
      width:50%;
      height:50px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-size:30px;
    }
    #PageCurr{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      background-color:red;
    }
    #PagePrev{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      background-color:green;
    }
    #PageNext{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      background-color:yellow;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- the tumblr blocks | if the outer div '#PageNavi' is placed
  inside the 'block:JumpPagination length="2"}' it will break, the
  pages also dont show up in the tumblr editor, go live to see it -->
  <DIV ID="PageNavi">
  {block:JumpPagination length="2"}

    {block:CurrentPage}

      {block:PreviousPage}

      <!-- this is the previous page, its allways
      rendered if current page greater than 1 -->
      <DIV ID="PagePrev">
      <a href="{PreviousPage}">{PageNumber}</a>
      </DIV>

        <!-- when previous page available, this block is also rendered
        too!! so overwrite #PageCurr by 'styling' it display none. -->
        <style>
        #PageCurr{ display:none; line-height:0; }
        </style>

      {/block:PreviousPage}

    <!-- this is the current page, allways rendered, BUT set 
    to display none if the previous page block is renderd so
    the “Previous Page” Button visible on the first page -->
    <DIV ID="PageCurr">
    <a href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a> 
    </DIV>

    {/block:CurrentPage}

    {block:JumpPage}

      <!-- this is the next page, its the next page. :P -->
      <DIV ID="PageNext">
      <a href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
      </DIV>

    {/block:JumpPage}

  {/block:JumpPagination}
  </DIV>
```

Or overwrite the url when block rendered so nothing needs to be hidden:

```
  <!-- some styling -->
  <style>
    #PageNavi{
      position:relative;
      width:50%;
      height:50px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-size:30px;
    }
    #PagePrev{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      background-color:green;
    }
    #PageNext{
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      background-color:yellow;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- the tumblr blocks | if the outer div '#PageNavi' is placed
  inside the 'block:JumpPagination length="2"}' it will break, the
  pages also dont show up in the tumblr editor, go live to see it -->
  <DIV ID="PageNavi">
  {block:JumpPagination length="2"}

    {block:CurrentPage}
    <DIV ID="PagePrev">
    <!-- magically overwrite current page with the previous page on block render, tada!! -->
    <a {block:PreviousPage}href="{PreviousPage}"{/block:PreviousPage} href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a> 
    </DIV>
    {/block:CurrentPage}

    {block:JumpPage}
    <DIV ID="PageNext">
    <a href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
    </DIV>
    {/block:JumpPage}

  {/block:JumpPagination}
  </DIV>
```

More ways can be extrapolated as well, if one thinks outside the DIV. ;)